# Enquiry on SPD and SPD-SL

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shoes

I am new to road bikes.
My pedals are 2010 shimano 105 - SPD-SL

Can spd shoes with spd cleats be used on spd-sl pedals?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does an SPD-SL AND SPD compatible pedal/shoe exist?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/does-an-spd-sl-and-spd-compatible-pedal-shoe-exist)

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  We've been around long enough for most common questions to have at least one answer, so please do use the search functionality before firing off a question.    I see you've read the Tour page, thank you for that.

Comment: No. Also, its pedal / pedals.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

The SPD-SL 3 bolt pattern is larger by several centimeters.

An SPD shoe has tread to make it easier to walk in the show off-road and a smaller, 2 bolt cleat mounting pattern. The tread would be in the way of mounting the SPD-SL cleat.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my answer inaccurate or incomplete?